# Why is my Exchange server generating event id 9187?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I am having an issue with an Exchange 2003 Server I setup.

It seems to be working for the most part (pending MX record / PTR). The problem I am having now is the Exchange server is generating event ID 9187 and looks like this.

```
Microsoft Exchange System Attendant failed to add the local computer as a member of the DS group object 'cn=Exchange Domain Servers,cn=Users,dc=campbellsurvey,dc=local'. 

Please stop all the Microsoft Exchange services, add the local computer into the group manually and restart all the services.
```

I don't have a clue what is going on, I have done a search and found a [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271335) relating to the problem. At first I thought it helped but about 15 mins later the error repeated. It seems to be trying what ever it is trying about every 15 mins.

Comment: I assume you have restarted the Microsoft Exchange System Attendant... right? Also, please could you link to the Microsoft solution you tried? (I'm guessing [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271335) but could you clarify?)

Comment: Yeah that is one I looked at

Comment: And by the way I have tried this 3 times, once I just restarted the service, another I actually stopped all of the services and made the changes and the 3rd I rebooted the system (Not in actual order).

Comment: OK, I started writing my answer before you put the comment about restarting the machine, but there are a couple of things in my answer that might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only ever seen this message logged after moving the Exchange server computer object to a different OU in Active Directory. Restarting the System Attendant and all dependant services (Warning: Information Store - don't do in the middle of the day!) should solve your problem.

Looking at [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271335), you can try taking the Exchange computer object out of the *Exchange Domain Servers* group, add it back in and bounce the System Attendant service.

Other quick digging reveals [this note](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=9187&eventno=1865&source=MSExchangeSA&phase=1) which basically says to make sure the primary group of your Exchange Server's computer object is **Domain Computers** as opposed to **Exchange Domain Servers**.

Failing all of the above, you could also try raising the diagnostic logging for the System Attendant to see if that reveals anything useful.

Comment: That very well may have been the problem, The primary domain group was NOT domain computers. I will know in about 20 mins whether it is fixed or not.

Comment: I'd also just like to add my standard spiel of checking your AD replication is all healthy and in sync - there's nothing like 2 Domain Controllers telling you 2 totally conflicting things :-)

Comment: yeah that was the first thing I was thinking, AD is work flawless.

Comment: Well its been 30 mins roughly and no error I am calling this one fixed.